# Data from state to FieldArray

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I have a redux form in which there is a button which will open a modal. In that modal the user will enter a value and submit it. Now the value should be stored in an array in redux form.
This can be done by user as many times.

I thought of using `FieldArray` as it will as many fields and all the data will be stored in the array. But how can I transfer the data from that modal to FieldArray?

https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/examples/fieldarrays/

https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/docs/api/fieldarray.md/

Answer (score 0):

By using the **change()** function you can achieve that

Import **change** from redux-from

```
import { change} from 'redux-form'
```

Once received all the data through modal, you can directly inject them. Probably inside a **handle change** function  as follows

```
change('fieldName', [{...}]);
```